# how to check if a url/link is safe in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

So I looked around and found nothing that helps or clarify this question, suppose you have a ruby on rails (5.2) API and you want to save some URLs as part of a model definition, how to determine that the URL you are saving is safe? and by safe I mean, avoid URLs/links that may contain phishing and deceptive sites.

Thx in advance .

Comment: Keep update your list of phishing and deceptive sites and check if link referencing one of those before saving ;)

Comment: There are services that do this.  Suggest searching for "safe url checker api" and find a service. Use the API to check before you save them and again before you serve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found so far, hope this help someone (that have the same requirement):

As pointed by @debugger there are multiple services that provide these functionalities, the best fit in my case are the ones below:

[Safe browsing google API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/?csw=1) no commercial purposes

[Web Risk](https://cloud.google.com/web-risk/docs/quickstart) for commercial purposes

The above are google APIs that can be used to check if a URL is safe or not.

In the last case you will be charged after a certain amount of request so maybe is a good idea to check if the URL/link is valid: [valid URL gem](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_url)